# error while loading shared libraries: cv2.so using php exec() for C++ app. on web app

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, lamp

I am using apache 2 with LAMP on Debian 7.0.0.  I build a C++ application, that includes openCV-2.4.0 using CodeBlocks 10.05.  When I initially ran the executable I got the following message

```
error while loading shared libraries: cv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I fixed this problem by copying cv2.so into /usr/local/lib, putting

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

into the .bashrc file of my home directory and running

```
. .bashrc
```

in my home directory.  However, LAMP applications run with www-data as the user and so, not surprisingly, when I ran the application on the web using php exec(), 
I again got the error message

```
error while loading shared libraries: cv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It is not clear how I can fix this problem since there would be no home directory, with a .bashrc file, for www-data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the line into `/etc/profile` or another system-wide location (`/etc/bashrc` probably won't work as Apache probably isn't being run by BASH.) You might need to restart Apache and/or the computer for this change to propagate.

However, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is one of the most misused environment variables, and the fact that you need it to run this executable is probably a symptom of a larger problem, most likely your executable isn't linked properly, OpenCV isn't installed properly, or your system isn't configured properly.

Given that you have OpenCV installed in `/usr/local`, I'm going to assume you compiled and installed it yourself. Do you have reason to believe that the version packaged in the Debian repos is insufficient/too old? If not, I'd recommend uninstalling your copy from `/usr/local` and installing the package `libcv-dev` (`sudo apt-get install libcv-dev`.) Then try recompiling your executable and see if it works without the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` hack. You would also need to recompile and reinstall anything else you compiled that depends on OpenCV (if any.)